# phonegap : pare xml (+ downloading it from web)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, cordova

I want to make a PhoneGap app to connect to a website with headers and get the response as XML
then parse it
:D simple with XML HTTP Request ... but the problem is that when I'm using it ... the browser locks till the response is completely back.

please let me know if there is a better and softer way to download and parse XML
(use anything you want. I mean jQuery and it's plugins + other libraries
or any changes that I can do in server-side codes)

and please let me know the best way to parse XML with every javascript library you know

UPDATE: making it simpler ...
I need a way to download XML without having my browser locked (like XMLHTTPRequest) while the action is in progress (+ I'm using file:/// protocol so ajax cross-domain won't work)

Comment: hello ... no one answering :| ????

Comment: If you look at a lot of the questions tagged with cordova, a lot haven't been answered.  Give it time.  Or... no one knows the answer.